# create a new column with the dupicated values in both columns in R

Tags: r

I inputted my file in R and obtained as data.frame.

```
x <- read_xlsx ("C:/Users/gtutk/Desktop/example.xlsx")
df <- data.frame (x)
    x  y
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  5
5   5  6
6   6  7
7   7  9
8   8 10
9   9 11
10 10 13
11 11 14
12 12 15
13 13 17
14 14 18
15 15 19
16 16 14
17 17 15
18 18 17
19 19 18
20 12 19
21 13 20
22 14 21
23 15 22
24 16 23
25 17 24
26 18 25
27 19 26
```

I want to creat a new merged excel file with duplicated values in two columns. Or removing the unique values existing in both two columns and finally getting only duplicated values in both two columns.
Expected file:

```
    new
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    9
8   10
9   11
10  13
11  14
12  15
13  17
14  18
15  19
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# If you have exactly two columns:
data.frame(new = do.call(intersect, df))
# For more than 2 columns:
data.frame(new = Reduce(intersect, df))

   new
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    9
8   10
9   11
10  13
11  14
12  15
13  17
14  18
15  19
```

Reproducible input data:

```
data.frame(
  x = c(
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 12, 13, 
    14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
  ),
  y = c(
    1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20,
    21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Is there any function for more than two columns? I mean, I have 8 columns and I want to create a new merged excel file with duplicated values in 8 columns.

Comment: if it is present in all coloumns, I want it. If it isnt even in one of 8 columns, I don't want it.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work. I added a column called Z into example.xlsx. 
Z column: 
z
1
2
3
7
9
10
13
14
17
20
21
22
24
25
27
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
but I got error: Error in (function (x, y)  : 
  unused argument (z = c(1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 10, 13, 14, 17, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 27, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40))

Comment: @GizemTutkun sorry, my mistake. I have added a modified solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have added extra columns, `z` and `w`, to show how to use this approach when there is more than 2 columns:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19), y = c(1, 
2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 14, 15, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -27L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(x = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), y = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

df$z <- rep(12, nrow(df))
df$w <-  rep(8, nrow(df))

df %>% 
  transmute(new = if_else(x %in% flatten(.[,-1]), x, NA_real_)) %>% 
  drop_na(new) %>% distinct

#>    new
#> 1    1
#> 2    2
#> 3    3
#> 4    5
#> 5    6
#> 6    7
#> 7    8
#> 8    9
#> 9   10
#> 10  11
#> 11  12
#> 12  13
#> 13  14
#> 14  15
#> 15  17
#> 16  18
#> 17  19
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following code, which can deal with the case of more than 2 columns

```
> d <- table(stack(df))

> data.frame(new = as.numeric(row.names(d))[rowSums(d > 0) == length(df)])
   new
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    9
8   10
9   11
10  13
11  14
12  15
13  17
14  18
15  19
```